# EF OrderBy directly on a datacontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Normally I use a full:

```
    var variable = (from r in db.mytable 
where r.field == 2 select r).tolist();
```

But if I am just doing something like:

```
 foreach (string p in db.mytable)
                    {
                       //do something here
                    }
```

How can I use a OrderBy?

Comment: Db.mytable.OrderBy(_ => _.SomeProperty)

Comment: Dennis's comment works perfectly...what is wrong with that? If you post it as a answer I will accept it. Wound up using: db.mytable.OrderBy(c=>c.mytable.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would suggest the use it of LINQ;
Second would be better the use of Async and TASK pattern to avoid deadlocks;
Third make the LINQ Query AsQueryable so all the sort and filter will be aplly on the SQL Server and not within your appplication.

From Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


public static void OrderByEx1()
{
    Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

    // Sort the Pet objects in the array by Pet.Age.
    IEnumerable<Pet> query =
        pets.AsQueryable().OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

    foreach (Pet pet in query)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I appreciate the extra steps and help as well!

Answer (score -1):

`foreach` doesn't work with `LINQ` to `entities`. If you have to apply `foeach` then you need to bring data in memory and bringing whole of the data in memory is definitely a bad idea.

I don't why you need `foreach` , it will be more helpful if you can tell the scenario. But if still need to do `foreach` then go with the below code

```
 var variable = (from r in db.mytable 
                 where r.field == 2 select r)
                .OrderBy(x=>x.Some_r_property)
                .ToList();

 foreach (var p in variable)
                    {
                       //do something here
                    }
```

Comment: @BradleyUffner  which part forach does work with Linq to entities unless it's in memory?

Comment: literally ALL of it.

Comment: I have faced multiple times `ForEach` doesn't work with `IQueryable`.

Comment: Then you were doing something wrong. `foreach` just requires an enumerator, which `IQueryable` provides.

Comment: And to make that work we are supposed to apply `.AsEnumerable()` and the moment we do it data gets loaded into memory. I am j not a pro but a 1 yr experience only so i m having my confusions..don't mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176530/discussion-between-sumit-raj-and-bradley-uffner).

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.asstreaming%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), specifically the reason why it is obsolete: `"LINQ queries are now streaming by default unless a retrying ExecutionStrategy is used. Calling this method will have no effect."`

Comment: @BradleyUffner   Thanks,It's a gd option.